# What if a company bought your patent while it was pending but later got rejected?

Tags: patent-applications, patent-pending

If a company outright bought the rights to the patent for X dollars while it was still in pending status, what would happen if later the patent is rejected?

Comment: This is really about contract law. What ever the contract defines holds.

Answer (score 1):

If they bought (licensed) your future rights, leaving you responsible for prosecuting the application and with no conditions, they would have wasted their money since there are no rights in the end.

If they paid you to assign the invention and application to them then you would be out of the picture and they could spend their money on an appeal, a continuation application or otherwise try to pursue getting something for their bargain.

Comment: I think this question probably should be closed. It’s a contracts question not a patent question.

Comment: You are correct - I thought it helpful to distinguish between an exclusive license and an assignment but didn’t do that very clearly.